# Single code coverage report for multiple test projects within one azure build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, reportgenerator

Tried creating a single code coverage report for multiple test projects within a single build pipeline - Multiple stages within a single build.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Run Test
      inputs:
        command: 'test'
        projects: |
          $(FunctionProjectBase)/$(FunctionShortName1)/*.csproj
        arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --collect "XPlat Code coverage"

    - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
      displayName: 'Publish code coverage report'
      inputs:
        codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
        summaryFileLocation: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Run Test
      inputs:
        command: 'test'
        projects: |
          $(FunctionProjectBase)/$(FunctionShortName2)/*.csproj
        arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --collect "XPlat Code coverage"

    - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
      displayName: 'Publish code coverage report'
      inputs:
        codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
        summaryFileLocation: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml
```

But this is not generating code coverage report on "Code coverage tab" Azure DevOps. It only generates a downloadable file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this is not generating code coverage report on "Code coverage tab" Azure DevOps. It only generates a downloadable file.

This is a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/662921/code-coverage-report-display-blank.html) on Azure devops. Now, we could only download the report, and could open it with Visual Studio.

**Azure devops only support the download link for .coverage files currently. The white page you see is a UI glitch. This scenario is only supposed to render a download link to the coverage file.**

Besides, this issue has been submitted in this earlier suggestion ticket linked here:

[support vstest .coverage "code coverage" build results tab](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366142/support-vstest-coverage-code-coverage-build-result.html)

This feature request is **On Roadmap**, I believe it will be released soon, you can vote and follow this thread to know its latest feedback.

Hope this helps.